# Replace a pattern in a 2d array with another pattern

Tags: java, arrays, replace, 2d, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a method that does the following: Replace every occurrence of the array A with the array B, where A is inside the 2D array C, then return the modified array. A, B, and C are 2-dimensional arrays of integers.

Given a rectangular array c, and another rectangular array a, with the dimensions of a <= those of c, find the first occurrence of a sub-array of c that matches a, and replace that sub-array with b (which must have the same dimensions as a).

```
public class ReplacePatterns {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
    //replace every instance of the pattern a with the pattern b inside c.
    //find a way to get the dimensions of a 2D array
    public static int[][] replacePattern(int[][] a, int[][] b, int[][] c){
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < c[0].length; j++){
                if(c[i][j] == a[i][j]){ //c[i][j] should match up with a[0][0].
                    int[][] d; //copy the array inside c to d.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "Pattern". /e Also, your method should probably be `static`.

Comment: Do you mean: Given a rectangular array `c`, and another rectangular array `a`, with the dimensions of `a` <= those of `c`, find the first occurrence of a sub-array of `c` that matches `a`, and replace that sub-array with `b` (which must have the same dimensions as `a`).  If so, please update your question.  If not, please explain your question better.

Comment: Define what you mean by `b` being "inside" `c` ... or what is "inside" what ... or what you even mean by "inside".  There is no such thing as a straightforward solution to a problem that is not properly specified.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, except it should do this for each occurrence of A.

Comment: By pattern, I mean a 2-dimensional rectangular arrangement of integers.

Comment: @Andy - don't tell us in comments.  UPDATE THE QUESTION.

Comment: Do you know how to search for one array within another?

Comment: I meant to say that every 2-dimensional array "A" inside the array "C" should be replaced with the 2-dimensional array "B" for each non-overlapping occurrence of "A".

Comment: @Andy - did you read my previous comment?

Comment: sorry, it wasn't showing up on my screen.

Comment: A and B has different items but same dimension length and A would be replaced with B is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming I understood the question correctly, you want something like this:

```
public class ReplacePatterns {

    //replace every instance of the pattern a with the pattern b inside c.
    //find a way to get the dimensions of a 2D array
    public static int[][] replace(int[][] a, int[][] b, int[][] c){
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < c[0].length; j++){
                if(c[i][j] == a[0][0]){ //c[i][j] should match up with a[0][0].
                    // Start verifying the rest of A
                    boolean flag = true;
                    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                        for (int l = 0; l < a[k].length; l++) {
                            if ((i+k) >= c.length || (j+l) >= c[0].length) {
                                flag = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (c[i+k][j+l] != a[k][l]) {
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // If all the values for A were exactly the same, then replace it all with whatever is in B
                    if (flag) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                            for (int l = 0; l < a[k].length; l++) {
                                c[i+k][j+l] = b[k][l];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static String prettyPrint(int[][] c) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < c[0].length; j++){
                sb.append("[" + c[i][j] + "]");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void test(int[][] patternA, int[][] patternB, int[][] patternC) {
        System.out.println("Pattern A:");
        System.out.println(prettyPrint(patternA));
        System.out.println("Pattern B:");
        System.out.println(prettyPrint(patternB));
        System.out.println("  Array C:");
        System.out.println(prettyPrint(patternC));

        int[][] result = ReplacePatterns.replace(patternA, patternB, patternC);

        System.out.println("  Result:");
        System.out.println(prettyPrint(result));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] patternA, patternB, patternC;

        System.out.println("Test1:");
        patternA = new int[][]{{1,1}, {1,1}};
        patternB = new int[][]{{3,3}, {3,3}};
        patternC = new int[][]{{0,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1}, {0,1,1,1}};
        test(patternA, patternB, patternC);

        System.out.println("Test2:");
        patternA = new int[][]{{1,1}, {1,1}};
        patternB = new int[][]{{5,6}, {7,8}};
        patternC = new int[][]{{0,1,1,1,0,1}, {1,1,1,0,1,1,1}, {0,1,1,1,1,1,1}};
        test(patternA, patternB, patternC);
    }
}
```

I even included two tests in there, for confirmation, but I'm pretty sure it will work for the general case.  It's probably inefficient, and might not work for huge arrays, but it gets the job done in this case.

The program outputs graphically the three given patterns (A, B and C), and prints out how C looks after the replacement has taken place.  In the second test run, you should see something like this:

```
Test2:
Pattern A:
[1][1]
[1][1]


Pattern B:
[5][6]
[7][8]


Array C:
[0][1][1][1][0][1]
[1][1][1][0][1][1]
[0][1][1][1][1][1]


Result:
[0][5][6][1][0][1]
[1][7][8][0][5][6]
[0][1][1][1][7][8]
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is demonstrated below. Please note that I did not give a thought on optimizing the code to minimize pattern checking. I am sure a better algorithm exists for finding the patterns. I took a naive approach of verifying the pattern on each node. notes inside the code.

```
//replace every instance of the pattern a with the pattern b inside c.
    //find a way to get the dimensions of a 2D array
    public int[][] replacePattern(int[][] a, int[][] b, int[][] c) {

        //first make d as copy of array c
        int[][] d = new int[c.length][c[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c[0].length; j++) {
                d[i][j] = c[i][j];
            }
        }

        //now scan array c for appearance of a. go over every node and on each node initiate a check if the pattern happens at that node
        //note the scan is done as long as we don't step out of array c dimensions
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length - a.length + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c[0].length - a[0].length + 1; j++) {
                //we verify pattern on each node as it can start on each of them
                boolean isPatternOcurring = true;
                for (int m = 0; m < a.length && isPatternOcurring; m++) {
                    for (int n = 0; j < a[0].length; n++) {
                        if (c[i + m][j + n] != a[m][n]) {
                            isPatternOcurring = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //if pattern occurs, then copy b into d
                if (isPatternOcurring) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < b.length; m++)
                        for (int n = 0; j < b[0].length; n++) 
                            d[i + m][j + n] = b[m][n]; 


                }
            }
        }


        return d;

    }
```